# Java program terminates when delay time is long

Tags: java, delay, execute

I'm writing a code that moves the mouse a bit any 10 mins.
However when I put a value higher than 100,000 (10 mins = 600,000 milliseconds)in the Robot.delay function the program only prints the "It works!" line and then terminate.

Why is this happening?

```
public class MoveEach10Mins {

static boolean flag;
static int CurrentXpos = 0;
static int CurrentYpos = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("It works!");

    try {
        Robot r = new Robot();
        while (true) {
            PointerInfo a = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
            Point b = a.getLocation();
            CurrentXpos = (int) b.getX();
            CurrentYpos = (int) b.getY();

            r.delay(600000);
            if (flag) {
                flag = false;
                r.mouseMove(CurrentXpos - 1, CurrentYpos);
                System.out.println("moved");
            } else {
                flag = true;
                r.mouseMove(CurrentXpos + 1, CurrentYpos);
                System.out.println("moved again");
            }

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }

}

}
```

Comment: DId you mean "exit" instead of "execute"?

Comment: Its probably jumping in the "catch" block.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#delay%28int%29):

> Throws:
>   IllegalArgumentException - if ms is not between 0 and 60,000 milliseconds inclusive